# How to add two numbers without using + operator in C using bit manipulation

Tags: c, recursion, bit-manipulation, bit

I recently came across this interview question and I'm not good in bit manipulation. Can you guys explain what the function 'f' does. I'm not sure what this recursive function does.

```
unsigned int f (unsigned int a , unsigned int b)
{
   return a ?   f ( (a&b) << 1, a ^b) : b;
}
```

I tried to paste the code in Visual Studio to test the logic but compiler is throwing some error message "cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'bool'. Is the condition statement (a ?) in the return missing something? but I'm sure the interview question was exactly same as mentioned above

Comment: This is a bloody awful interview question.

Comment: this is summation without `+` http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-two-numbers-without-using-arithmetic-operators/

Comment: @IlyaBursov: Ah, very good.  Another interview question to add to my satchel.

Comment: It's a great interview question: For the majority of programmers, it is not a test of skill, it a test of whether or not they have seen that trick in the past.  Run from employers who are screening for "stupid programmer tricks."

Comment: @WayneConrad: In that sense, yes, it's fantastic ;)

Comment: Something doesn't seem right here.  Shouldn't the two terms be reversed?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it doesn't matter, as a+b = b+a

Comment: @IlyaBursov: Ah, of course.

Comment: if you have problems with compiler, use `return (a!=0) ? f( (a&b) << 1, a ^b) : b;`

Comment: Is there any way to figure this out besides trying a bunch of inputs and noting the results end up in the sum and just saying that's what it does after so many tests?

Comment: @KevinDiTragila yes. Since the only options for each place are `0+0=0`, `1+1=0`(carry 1)  , or `0+1=1`/`1+0=1` you can select all instances of each category by using the bitwise operators, and proceed from there.

Comment: This is not an "aha" puzzle.  If you can't answer this question by trying examples and reasoning about the logic you are not qualified to work on C code that relies on bit manipulation.  If you do systems level programming you will have to understand functions vastly more complicated than this every day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well already a few people in the comments mentioning this just adds two numbers.  I'm not sure of a better way to figure that out than just try some inputs and note the results.

Ex:

```
f(5,1) --> returns f(2,4) --> returns f(0,6) --> returns 6

 1.) 5&1 = 1 bit shifted = 2:  5^1 = 4
 2.) 2&4 = 0 bit shifted = 0:  2^4 = 6
 3.) a = 0 so return b of 6

f(4,3) --> returns f(0,7) --> returns 7

1.) 4&3 = 0 bit shifted = 0:  4^3 = 7
2.) a = 0 so return b of 7
```

After you show a few examples of the output I suppose you could postulate f returns the two inputs added together.

Answer (score 0):

The prospective employer is either very thorough, or enjoys cruel & unusual punishment.

For the answer to the question, a review of the freely available chapter 2 from [**HackersDelight**](http://hackersdelight.org/basics2.pdf) is worth its weight in gold. The addition operator in the function is taken from [**HAKMEM memo -- Item 23**](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/hbaker/hakmem/boolean.html#item23) and substitutes a left-shift in place of multiplying by 2. The original HAKMEM memo proposes:

```
(A AND B) + (A OR B) = A + B = (A XOR B) + 2 (A AND B)
```

or re-written in C:

```
x + y = (x ^ y) + 2 * (x & y)
```

The creative employer then uses `(x & y) << 1` in place of `2 * (x & y)` and recursion to compute to sum and `or` `a` and `b` until `a` = `0` at which time `b` is returned.

Glad it wasn't my interview.